# How to set the default highlight option when clicking a selectbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

for example,the birthday select box has year, I want to set the year to 1980 when I click the select box.using js jquery? Pseudocode is ok,thanks

**update**
the following code worked, but why if I change the focus to click,
the highlight option is not on 1980?

```
$('#birthday_y').focus(function() {
    if (!$(this).val()){
        $(this).val('1980');
    }
});
```

Comment: Your question tittle and the "example" you provide does not match.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `selected` attribute to the desired `option`:

```html
Choose year:
<select>
  <option>1975</option>
  <option>1976</option>
  <option>1977</option>
  <option>1978</option>
  <option>1979</option>
  <option selected>1980</option>
  <option>1981</option>
  <option>1982</option>
  <option>1973</option>
  <option>1984</option>
  <option>1985</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it is not what I expect, I want the default  select is blank when I load the page,when I click the it, the drop menu curosr point to the 1980

Comment: @overstack You can't change the position of the cursor.